# Почему в асинхронной функции при задержке не переключается на другую работу?

Tags: python, async-await, asyncio

Тестирую асинхронный ping. По умолчанию host3 отбрасываю в исключения, а host6 недоступный. По логике при проверке недоступного host3 во время ожидания должны сразу переключиться на проверку других хостов, но всё равно происходит ожидание. Почему так?

[image: example]

```
import aioping
import asyncio
from socket import gaierror


async def do_ping(host):
    try:
        await aioping.ping(host, timeout=1)
        print("UP", host)
    except TimeoutError:
        print("DOWN:", host)
    except gaierror:
        print("EXCEPTION:", host)


async def main():
    hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3', 'host4', 'host5', 'host6']
    for serv in hosts:
        task = asyncio.create_task(do_ping(serv))
        await task


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы в цикле создаете таск, и тут же ждете его завершения, до окончания ожидания код в этой функции не продолжает работать (код буквально ждет на `await`, пока таск не завершится, другие таски не создаются).

Вместо этого нужно сформировать список тасков и ожидать их завершения параллельно через [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait). В примере ping заменил на ожидание со случайной длительностью.

```
import asyncio
import random


async def do_ping(host):
    timeout = 1.0
    time = random.random() * 1.5
    if time <= timeout:
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        if random.random() < 0.2:
            print("EXCEPTION:", host)
        else:
            print("UP", host)
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
        print("DOWN", host)


async def main():
    hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3', 'host4', 'host5', 'host6']
    await asyncio.wait([asyncio.create_task(do_ping(serv)) for serv in hosts])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Пример вывода:

```
UP host4
UP host1
EXCEPTION: host2
DOWN host3
DOWN host5
DOWN host6
```

Comment: также, + возбудилось исключение DeprecationWarning на asyncio.wait

Comment: @legion088 предупреждение поправил, дополнил пример

Comment: да, работает, спасибо! только исключение всё равно заставляет ждать.

Comment: @legion088 если исключение тромозит все таски, то возможно в самом aioping какой-то синхронный код, на котором вылетает исключение. Это можно какими-нибудь костылями поправить, но скорее всего сам aioping нужно исправлять.

Comment: согласен. необходимо проанализировать исключение gaierror!

Comment: @legion088 для эксперимента попробуйте в main в начале добавить `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` `loop.set_default_executor(ProcessPoolExecutor)` (ProcessPoolExecutor импортировать из `concurrent.futures`), это по идее заставит `loop.getaddrinfo` внутри ping запускаться в отдельном процессе, а не в потоке, теоретически может помочь